# Trailing newline included in variable assignment after grep, and sent to GitHub actions output

Tags: bash, docker, sed, grep, github-actions

I've got a bash script in a GitHub action that greps for image tags, then replaces them in a docker-compose.yml.

```bash
# docker-compose.yml from a JSON payload
docker_compose='"services:\n  api:\n    proxy: ghcr.io/org/api:main-4095094301\n    ports:\n      - 0:80\n    restart: always\n\n  proxy:\n    image: ghcr.io/org/proxy:main-4095124301\n    depends_on:\n      - api\n    environment:\n      - \"ENVIRONMENT=dev\"\n      - \"PORT=8000\"\n    ports:\n      - 0:3000\n    restart: always\n\n ..."'

# Extract the tag of each image, send to GitHub actions output
echo "proxy_tag=$(echo -n $docker_compose | grep -oP 'proxy:\K[-\w]+')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

If I remove the `>>` operator to echo the output, everything looks OK:

```
proxy_tag=main-4095094301
```

But when I feed it into `sed` later in a different step of the pipeline, an extra newline character seems to come from nowhere:

```bash
echo "running s/PROXY_TAG/$proxy_tag/"
sed -i "s/PROXY_TAG/$proxy_tag/" docker-compose.yml

# running s/PROXY_TAG/main-4095094301
# /
# sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command
# Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I've tried some common suggestions eg. piping output through `tr -d '\n'`:

`echo "proxy_tag=$(echo -n $docker_compose | grep -oP 'proxy:\K[-\w]+' | tr -d '\n')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT`

Is there something missing I don't understand about bash vars or Github actions?

See below a more complete context of how where these commands are being used.

```yaml
name: Update Docker Compose

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      proxy_tag:
        description: proxy_tag
        type: string
        required: false
      # api_tag:
      # site_tag:

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Fetch docker-compose
        id: get-tags
        run: |
            docker_compose=$(curl ...)

            echo "proxy_tag=$(echo -n $docker_compose | grep -oP 'proxy:\K[-\w]+')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "api_tag=$(echo $docker_compose | grep -oP 'api:\K[-\w]+')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
            echo "site_tag=$(echo $docker_compose | grep -oP 'site:\K[-\w]+')" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

      - name: Replace tags docker-compose
        env:
          proxy_tag: >
            ${{ github.event_name == 'workflow_dispatch'
                && github.event.inputs.proxy_tag
              || steps.get-tags.outputs.proxy_tag
              || 'latest'
            }}
          # api_tag: >
          # site_tag: >
        run: |
          echo "Setting [$proxy_tag]"

          sed -i "s/PROXY_TAG/$proxy_tag/" docker-compose.yml
          sed -i "s/API_TAG/$api_tag/" docker-compose.yml
          sed -i "s/SITE_TAG/$site_tag/" docker-compose.yml

        # Outputs:
        #   Setting [main-4095094301       # <--- notice the newline
        #   ]
        #
        #   sed: -e expression #1, char 18: unterminated `s' command
        #   Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: Typo: Missing $ from `GITHUB_OUTPUT` in the first code block.

Comment: I suspect that the newline being added is from YAML's folding using `>`. Try `>-` to not add the last newline.

Comment: This (https://yaml-multiline.info/) might be helpful for live experimentation with YAML.

Comment: You should always quote variables for expansion: change `$(echo -n $docker_compose |` to `$(echo -n "$docker_compose" |` (the command substitution sets up a new quoting context).

Comment: @Azeem you were 100% correct, trailing newline on the YAML env vars, `>-` fixed it. Bloody beautiful, please reply again as an Answer so I can mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the newline character being added is from the YAML's folding using `>` while setting your environment variables under `env`. Try `>-` to not add (strip) the last newline character.

This (https://yaml-multiline.info/) might be helpful for live experimentation with YAML.

Comment: Thanks @Azeem, wouldn't have found this solution without you

Answer (score 1):

Worst case, if you're using `bash`,

```
$: proxy_tag="main-4095094301
" # embedded newline for example

$: echo "[$proxy_tag]" # show with embedded newline
[main-4095094301
]

$: echo "[${proxy_tag%$'\n'}]" # show with embedded newline removed
[main-4095094301]

$: echo PROXY_TAG | sed "s/PROXY_TAG/$proxy_tag/" # syntax error with embedded newline
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated `s' command

$: echo PROXY_TAG | sed "s/PROXY_TAG/${proxy_tag%$'\n'}/" # removed, syntax ok
main-4095094301
```

That seems error-prone to me, though, and I prefer to do most of my basic string processing right in the interpreter unless it's huge and I need it faster, so I'd probably do something based on this -

```
$: docker_compose=$'services:\n  api:\n    proxy: ghcr.io/org/api:main-4095094301\n    ports:\n      - 0:80\n    restart: always\n\n  proxy:\n    image: ghcr.io/org/proxy:main-4095124301\n    depends_on:\n      - api\n    environment:\n      - "ENVIRONMENT=dev"\n      - "PORT=8000"\n    ports:\n      - 0:3000\n    restart: always\n\n ...' # note $'...' for clean quotes and newlines

$: echo "[$docker_compose]"
[services:
  api:
    proxy: ghcr.io/org/api:main-4095094301
    ports:
      - 0:80
    restart: always

  proxy:
    image: ghcr.io/org/proxy:main-4095124301
    depends_on:
      - api
    environment:
      - "ENVIRONMENT=dev"
      - "PORT=8000"
    ports:
      - 0:3000
    restart: always

 ...]

$: shopt -s extglob                            # enable extended globbing
$: tmp="${docker_compose##* proxy: *([^:]):}"  # trim front - *(...) is "0 or more"
$: proxy_tag="${tmp%%$'\n'*}"                  # trim after, from 1st newline on
$: echo "[$proxy_tag]"                         # show that it's clean
[main-4095094301]
```